# How to calculate sum of a finite series (sequence)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Find finite sum ?
$$1^2\cdot 2^0+2^2\cdot 2^1+3^2\cdot 2^2+4^2\cdot 2^3+\cdots+n^2\cdot 2^{n-1}$$

Comment: Write $n^2 = n(n-1) + n$. Differentiate a geometric sum $x^0 + x^1 + \ldots x^k$ (twice). Check for similarities.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the slightly simpler problem of finding $$\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k\;?$$

Comment: $2^n ((n-2) n+3)-3$

Comment: See the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn). (Under the "added note", in particular.)

Answer (score 2):

Hints (look at the comments, too):

$$|x|<1\implies \frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\implies\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}\implies$$

$$\implies\frac2{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^2x^{n-2}
-\sum_{n=2}^\infty nx^{n-2}$$

Now multiply the whole second line above by $\,x\,$ and....well, and make some mathematics then.

Answer (score 1):

$1^2\cdot 2^0+2^2\cdot 2^1+3^2\cdot 2^2+4^2\cdot 2^3+\cdots+n^2\cdot 2^{n-1}=S$-->1
multiply eq1 with $2$ and sustract from it which is,
$$1^2.2^0+(2^2-1^2)2^1+......+(n^2-(n-1)^2).2^{n-1}-n^2.2^n=S$$
$$1^2.2^0+(2+1).2^1+(3+2).2^2+......+(n+(n-1).2^{n-1}-n^2.2^n=S$$
$$1.2^0+2.2^1+3.2^2+.......n.2^{n-1}+2(1.2^0+2.2^1+3.2^2+.......n.2^{n-1})-n^2.2^n-n.2.{n-1}=S$$
let,$$1.2^0+2.2^1+3.2^2+.......n.2^{n-1}=X$$
then,$$S=3X-n^2.2^n-n.2^{n-1}$$
you can calculate x if you know the technique asked by Brian.M.Scott in comments